# apply subtraction of columns for particular rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have one DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_A':[1,0,3], 'col_B':[2,0,1]})
```

I need to find difference of columns for rows where sum of elements in row is more than 0.

```
null_index = df[df.sum(axis=1)==0].index
df['col_B'] = (df.loc[~df.index.isin(null_index),'col_B']-df.loc[~df.index.isin(null_index),'col_A'])/df.loc[~df.index.isin(null_inde),'col_A']
```

I get a DataFrame with shape of (2,1) but I need (3,1) but for the 2nd row nothing would happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to mask `col_B` wherever the row sum is greater than 0.

```
df.col_B.mask(df.sum(1) > 0, df.col_B - df.col_A, inplace=True)

df
#        col_A  col_B
# 0      1      1
# 1      0      0
# 2      3     -2
```

Or doing much the same without `df.mask` using index information will likely be slower.

```
df.loc[df.sum(1) > 0, 'col_B'] = df.col_B - df.col_A
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite `col_B` with the difference only in rows with sum greater than 0:

```
mask = df.sum(axis=1) == 0
df.loc[mask, 'col_B'] = df.loc[mask].diff(axis=1)['col_B'].astype(int)
df
   col_A  col_B
0      1      1
1      0      0
2      3     -2
```